# How should I understand this following sentence grammatically?

Tags: sentence-construction

How should I understand the following passage simply?

Could you clarify this passage with simple stracture?

Why does the writer begin with the word 'in'?

Thanks.

The passage:

> In Gautama the Buddha we have a master-mind from the East second to
> none so far as the influence on the thought and life of the human race
> is concerned, and, sacred to all as the founder of a religious
> tradition whose hold is hardly less wide and deep than any other.

Source: P. 9
Buddhism in a Nutshell
BY
NARADA THERA

Comment: I would understand initial ***in** X* in such contexts as "reduced" from something like ***in the case of** X, **regarding** X, **turning to** X, **if we look at** X,...*

Answer (score 1):

'In' can be used to mean 'in the person or case of' - **in** Gautama the Buddha we have a master-mind from the East; **in** our Prime Minister we have a great genius and living saint; **in** St Pauls Cathedral we have a jewel of architecture.